# NextJS & firebase credentials

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

So here's the situation: I'm setting up a small nextjs app to interact with a firebase database (+storage).

The problem is that the firebase app instance now lives in the server components, as I thought it wouldn't be great to send the 'credentials' (api key and stuff) to the client.

This turned out to be not so great, as the app instance lifetime seemed to be quite random, or at least, I couldn't control it properly (I had a singleton living there). So meaning, recreate it on every request.

Finally, I know my setup is pretty bad, but I ended up moving the firebase instance to the client components.
But then this means that the api key, app id and stuff are sent to the client, and I was wondering what was the proper way of doing this?

(most of the online resources I find sends them to the client via 'env variables' prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC`, which I also ended up doing)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: It's unavoidable for the client app to get a hold of the the firebase app configuration.  It's also not a security problem as long as you have security rules set up to correctly allow or deny access to the database according to your security requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Firebase web SDK?, if so, you don't have to worry about the keys you use to initialize the app, as they are just used by Firebase to identify your app and not to control access to the database or Cloud Storage data. Read: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/security-checklist#api-keys-not-secret

Now, if you are using the Firebase admin SDK, you could create internal API routes to fetch whatever data you need from your Firestore or cloud database, then you could fetch those API routes in your client components without the need of public keys in your FE.

Comment: Yes, web SDK only, no admin, thanks for the answer!